# AV Foundation QR scanner not calling captureOutput

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am having an issue with this code using Xcode 9 and Swift. It will build fully and run on my device, showing the camera output properly, but will not actually call captureOutput to process the data.

```
eimport UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Creating session
        print("Creating Session")
        let session = AVCaptureSession()

        //Define capture devcie AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
        print("Defining Capturing device")
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        do
        {
            print("Initialzing input")
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
            session.addInput(input)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("ERROR")
        }

        print("Initializing output")
        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)

        //self.view.bringSubview(toFront: square)

        session.startRunning()
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        print("Processing Data.")
        if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0
        {
            if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            {
                if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr
                {
                    print("Found a pdf417.")
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Scanner", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in
                        UIPasteboard.general.string = object.stringValue
                    }))

                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

In the console, I am only getting output down to the print("Initializing output"). This tells me that the captureOutput function is not being called by the delegate. I have tried changing the scope of the session to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no `captureOutput(_:didOutputMetadataObjects:from:)`. What you should implement is [`metadataOutput(_:didOutput:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutputobjectsdelegate/1389481-metadataoutput).